# Generation of All Invertible Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, finite-fields, matrix-calculus

I am seeking an efficient and elegant method to construct all invertible matrices in $GL_n(F)$. While I am aware that one can randomly generate matrices and check for invertibility, I aim to systematically construct all $(q^n-1)(q^n-q^1)(q^n-q^2)...(q^n-q^{n-1})$ invertible matrices, where $F$ is finite field and $q = |F|$.

To illustrate, consider the straightforward method of constructing all subsets of a given set $S$ by numbering them from $0$ to $2^{|S|}-1$. I am hoping for a similar systematic approach, if one exists.

Comment: so one way is to generate all $F^{n\times n}$ and always check. Most are invertible, usually

Comment: try to do a recursive algorithm that for any $m\le n$ gives you all the full rank matrices $m\times n$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799854/is-the-l-in-lu-factorization-unique#comment3675501_1799854

Generate them as LU-factorization, (products of L and U matrices), where the L has only 1s in the diagonal and the U has no zeroes in the diagonal.

Comment: Please add what F is.

Comment: F is finete field.